# How to get DocumentBuilder to retain line breaks such as \r CRs and \n LFs

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, document

I have a byte stream that has CRs (carriage returns) and LFs (line feeds). When i create an instance of DocumentBuilder to parse the stream, it removes these and replaces them with a space. Any suggestions on how i can retain the \r and \n ?

Sample stream :

```
"Meeting with the team
1
2
3"
```

Code :

```
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
document = docBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(rawData));
```

Result :

```
Meeting with the team 1 2 3
```

Comment: Your sample stream is not XML and will therefore be rejected by the DocumentBuilder.

Comment: Im sry but i posted a snippet of the XML. the value of an element is that i have added.